# MySQL query to return non unique column combination

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with computerid, userid, and few other columns. Now I want a query which would return all the records where computerid value is shared by more than one user.  Find below sample data:

```
computerid  userid
100         5     
105         10    
110         6     
100         7     
101         11    
100         5     
105         10    
101         11
```

For above set of data mysql query should return below results because in this case computerid is shared by two user ids.

```
computerid  userid
100         5     
100         7
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Just one note - This table as around 1 million records. There would be few records where multiple users would have same computerid. just wondering which query would be fast enough performance wise.

Comment: What is fast enough? Do you know how to add indexes to your table?

Comment: Also, what does the query `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT computerid) FROM table1` return for your table?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.computerid, T2.userid
FROM (
    SELECT computerid
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY computerid
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT userid) > 1
) T1
JOIN table1 T2
ON T1.computerid = T2.computerid
```

Result:

```
computerid  userid
100         5
100         7
```

Add an index on (computerid) to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(computerid) , userid FROM table  
WHERE computerid IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT(computerid)  FROM table GROUP BY computerid HAVING COUNT(computerid)>1)
```

Comment: You are missing the DISTINCT keyword in two places.

Comment: In my testing on 100000 rows of test data this solution takes a very long time to execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.computerid, a.userId
FROM table a
JOIN (
    SELECT computerId
    FROM table
    GROUP BY computerId
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT userId) > 1
) b ON a.computerId = b.computerId
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without subqueries

```
SELECT 
  t1.*
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2
  ON t1.computerid = t2.computerid AND t1.userid != t2.userid
WHERE
  t2.userid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  t1.computerid, t1.userid;
```

Assuming that there are few computers with more than one user, this should be relatively fast.

Comment: In my local testing on 100000 rows of test data, this runs twice as slowly as my solution (1.6s instead of 0.8s).

Comment: Regarding *Assuming that there are few computers with more than one user*, only 100 computers had more than one user in my test.